# How to setup grafana behind nginx proxy? I have tried but i am seeing different interface

Tags: nginx, debian, grafana

For Grafana I am seeing following

[image]

My nigix.conf contains following

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Grafana instance must be made aware of, that it needs to deliver/generate the links to the static assets under "/grafana".

In my dockerized (`docker-compose` actually) setup I have the following setup in `nginx.conf`:

```
proxy_pass     http://grafana:3000/;
```

The service is called `grafana` that's why the name difference.
For Grafana itself an env var is passed:

```
GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: 'http://grafana:3000/grafana/'
```

I am not sure if you are running dockerized or not.
Given the case not, you could also just see the documentation and adjust your `grafana.ini` according to the [documentation for running behind a reverse proxy](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/behind_proxy/). The "Examples with sub path" is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi mweirauch, do you have a running example of a proxied grafana, prossibly in docker-compose? I'm struggling with it so much!

Comment: @marcopeg No, I dropped nginx and don't have a working example anymore. But I guess there's a lot out there which can be searched for.